# Electrostatic attraction between charges in different media

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-current, charge

Imagine you have two non-conducting spheres of density *a* (*a* < density of water). Therefore the spheres float on the surface of water with a portion of their bodies immersed in water. Now how do you compute the electrostatic force of attraction between the spheres?
What does electric field line distribution look like in this situation? What if the center of the sphere is exactly on the line separation of the two media?

Answer (score 0):

Without doing any calculation, I would say the field lines angle with the surface of the spheres is going to be different due to the electric polarization.